# Loop in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to Sql server.I have a stored procedure.I need to select records from a table1 upto a specific time in a date and update status true in that table1.Also need to select records from table 2   and delete from each record satisfies condition from that table 2 after inserting the selected records into table 3.
Anyone have a solution please help.Thanks in advance.

```
Table 1:

ID   Name  Status Stime
1     abc    0    2017-08-15 12:55:30
2     cde    0    2017-08-15 15:55:30
3     xxx    0    2017-08-15 17:55:30

Table 2:
BID   key        Sdate                       Edate
1    12   2017-08-15 10:00:30              2017-08-15 10:55:30
2    123  2017-08-15 18:00:30              2017-08-15 18:55:30
3    13   2017-08-15 19:00:30              2017-08-15 19:55:30

    eg:CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DetailsUpdate
    AS
    SELECT * FROM Table 1 where Stime > 01:00:00
    Update Table 1  status  = 1

   Select Table 2  where Sdate >= 01:00:00

     Insert into a table 1
     Delete from table 2
```

Comment: Since you said that you are new, you should know that loops should be avoided at all cost. They are not performant. Think in sets. With that being said, sample data and expected output is usually needed for most questions.

Comment: If you are inserting a data set into a temp table, you don't need to loop through the records to do the delete. Delete from table 2, select from temp table.

Comment: What is the propose of a temp table? You can insert or select what you just deleted using `OUTPUT` You need to change your mind about thinking procedural vs set based operations.

Answer (score 0):

Without any real sample data... this seems like what you are trying to do.

```
update table1
set someCol = 'someVal'
where anotherColumn in (select anotherColumn from table1 where <condition>)


delete t2
from table2 t2
inner join
table3 t3 on t3.colID = t2.colID
where <some condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to update Status Column in Table1 based on a condition (time > 1:00:00). Then you want to delete Records from Table2 based on same condition and insert deleted records in table 3.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DetailsUpdate
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE table1
SET [Status]= 'True'
WHERE CAST(Stime AS TIME) > '01:00:00'

DELETE FROM table2
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO Table3
WHERE CAST(Stime AS TIME) > '01:00:00'

END
```